# Sqlite database backup and restore in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask sqlalchemy to create db which in turns create a app.db files to store tables and data. Now for the backup it should be simple to just take a copy of app.db somewhere in the server. But suppose while the app is writing data to app.db and we make a copy at that time then we might have inconsistent app.db file.

How do we maintain the consistency of the backup. I can implement locks to do so. But I was wondering on standard and good solutions for database backup and how is this implemented in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has the [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) for this, but it is not available in the built-in Python driver.

You could

- use the [APSW library](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/) for the backup; or
- execute the `.backup` command in the [`sqlite3` command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html); or
- run [BEGIN IMMEDIATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) to prevent other connections from writing to the DB, and copy the file(s).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted also create backups of my SQL file, which stores data from my Flask.
Since my Flask web don't have too many users, and the database don't carry more than 4 small-medium size tables I did the following:

```
#Using Linux cmd
cd pathOfMyDb
nano backupDbRub.sh # backupDBRun is the name of the file that will be called periodically
```

Nano text editor will open a file  and you can write the following

```
#!/bin/bash

current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S");
sep='"';
file_name = '_site.db"';

functionB = '.backup ';

queryWrite = "$functionB$sep$current_time$file_name";

echo "$queryWrite";

sqlite3 yoursqlitefile.db  "$queryWrite"
```

Basically with this code we create a function ($queryWrite) which will do a copy of the current database with a timestamp. Now in Unix you will have to modify the crontab file.
Write in the Unix terminal

```
crontab -e
```

in this new file , as explained in this [post](https://medium.com/@fotios.floros/linux-backup-script-1722cc9c2bf6) you should add the periodicity (in my case , for testing purposed, I wanted to run it every minute to check it is working.

`* * * * * /backupDbRub.sh`

Think that the copies will appear in the folder you choose in the $querywrite sentence. So you can find them there.

In case you want to test that the script works, you must go to the folder where this script and run
`/backupDbRub.sh` 
This should print the 'echo' sentence called in your file. Sometimes you did not provide permissions in this file, so you should add permissions with 'chmod -x', or whatever other you need to set up.